# Android - Which is best way to store the mp3 files

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I am new to android. I am going to develop a simple mp3 application. There will be some mp3 tones in my app. I want to play the tones on click in the list item. Now my question is Which is the best way to store the mp3 files in my app.

1) SQLite

2) XML

3) folder

Please let me some good idea to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store them in a folder. There must be any resource the [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) entrys refer to, because this is just a database. So storing them in a folder is not a question I think...

And XML is used to define UI Things like the interface.
This is because of the Model-View-Controller pattern if you want to know more about that [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

If you safed it in the raw folder(it´s located in the res folder, if you dont have one-> create one) of your project than this should be suitable for you

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

If you got it somewhere else this should fit your needs

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("/path/to/file.mp3"); // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

For more informations about MediaPlayer [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Comment: Hi @Burnaut.. The next question will be that only..!! :-) Can you give me any sample for this app??

Comment: @Vijay I would appreciate it if you give me an upvote and accept the answer if it helped you